# Is there a need to use middleware in redux? If RTK query is being used

Tags: redux, frontend, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

If I am using an external api or fetching data from database then is there any need for me to use middleware in redux toolkit or RTK query can do all the work for me?

Answer (score 1):

I found this on their the official RTK User Guide Docs:

[User Guide | Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide)

> Redux Toolkit's RTK Query data fetching API is a purpose built data
> fetching and caching solution for Redux apps, and can eliminate the
> need to write any thunks or reducers to manage data fetching.